# Rotate with scipy without interpolation

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to rotate without interpolation my 3D stack (3D numpy array) on the (x,y) plane (around the z axis). To do this, I'm using the rotate function from the package Scipy as follows:

```
ske_rotate = scipy.ndimage.rotate(stack, angle, (1, 0), False, None, 0, 'constant', 0.0, False)
```

The issue is that I obtain a distorted rotated 3D stack as showed in my two figures.

Before:

[image: Before rotation]

After:

[image: After rotation]

Here are the constructed 3D skeletons of the 3D stacks before and after rotation. One can remark that the skeletons are different (points are added on the skeleton after rotation) which means that (in a quantitative way) the shape was modified after rotation.

[3D Skeleton before rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHnnT.png)

[3D Skeleton after rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFNtI.png)

For 2D analysis, I extract the 39 slice from the two stacks. The two stacks have the same size (stack.shape=(120,120,120)). Note that if we remove the option in the line code, the stacks will have different sizes. The degree of rotation is 10°

[Original stack: slice 39](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxQhZ.png)
[Rotated stack: slice 39](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QnBe.png)

With the interpolation method :
    ske_rotate = scipy.ndimage.rotate(stack, angle)

The 3D skeleton becomes as in the following figure (as if new shape is added..):
[3D skeleton after a rotation with interpolation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6FcU.png)

How can I obtain free distorted rotated 3D stack ?

Comment: The screenshots are not really speaking as they are also influenced by lighting. Please simplify the issue by plotting in 2D with matplotlib (or any other plotting library) and specify in a quantitative way how the rotated image does not match your expectation.

Comment: I edited by adding 3D constructed skeleton from the initial 3D stack and the rotation one. They are different. This show that the stack was modified after rotation

Comment: I tried to plot in 2D with: plt.matplotlib(my_stack). But it doesn't plot anything. It's possible to plot 2D figure from a 3D stack with matplotlib ?

Comment: what is `stack.shape`? With matplotlib, you can plot slices of the stack: `plt.imshow(stack[0])` for instance. As far as your observations go in 3D, as the rendering involves interpolation it is impossible to tell at this point whether the difference is due to the rotation or the rendering.

Comment: I edited by adding the plot of the same slice from the two stacks

Comment: How come the 2D plot is black and white?

Comment: It's a binary stack. And I used: plt.imshow(stack[39,:,:],cmap='gray')

Comment: The 3D plot seems to have more than binary coding, am I wrong?

Comment: No it's really binary since before the plot, I made: stack_original[stack_original>0]=255

Comment: With the invokation in your question, the rotation will pick up the value in a neighboring cell according to the rotation. If the rotated location is not on the 255 level, you will obtain 0. This type of transformation does not guarantee "conservation of the pixels" and is very crude. Interpolated data will be more accurate.

Comment: Indeed, your explanation is quite good. However, when I'm using the interpolation as shown in the edited post, the skeleton result is really bad since, as what I understand, the interpolation add lot of points on the stack's shape.

Comment: @javier did you manage to solve this?  I believe I'm working with a very similar problem